# Declare Private Variables in C++

Tags: c++

I want to create some private variables, but when i compile the program i get an error. If I move the variables above the class SimpleOpenNIViewer than it works.

This is the error Messages:
/Workspace/virtual-reality/main.cpp:16:56: error: expected identifier before ‘new’
         PointCloud::Ptr cloud_previous2 (new PointCloud);

This is how I have written the code. Can anyone tell me why this doesnt work?

```
class SimpleOpenNIViewer
     {
        private:
            PointCloud<PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr cloud_previous2 (new PointCloud<PointXYZRGBA>);
            PointCloud<PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr cloud_previous1 (new PointCloud<PointXYZRGBA>);
            PointCloud<PointXYZHSV>::Ptr cloud_HSVPrev2(new PointCloud<PointXYZHSV>);
            PointCloud<PointXYZHSV>::Ptr cloud_HSVPrev1(new PointCloud<PointXYZHSV>);
            PointCloud<PointXYZHSV>::Ptr cloud_HSVCurr(new PointCloud<PointXYZHSV>);
```

Comment: Please share the error your getting.

Comment: _"If I move the variables above the class"_. You mean make them global variables ?

Comment: Yes, If I move them above the class SimpleOpenNIViewer. This way it works to compile

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have included all the relevant headers or forward declared classes your variables depend on.

Your class declaration also lacks a closing brace and semi colon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class SimpleOpenNIViewer
     {
        private:
            PointCloud<PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr cloud_previous2 = new PointCloud<PointXYZRGBA>;
            PointCloud<PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr cloud_previous1 = new PointCloud<PointXYZRGBA>;
            PointCloud<PointXYZHSV>::Ptr cloud_HSVPrev2 = new PointCloud<PointXYZHSV>;
            PointCloud<PointXYZHSV>::Ptr cloud_HSVPrev1 = new PointCloud<PointXYZHSV>;
            PointCloud<PointXYZHSV>::Ptr cloud_HSVCurr = new PointCloud<PointXYZHSV>;
```

Comment: I did try, but I got a different error. /Workspace/virtual-reality/main.cpp:16:88: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
             PointCloud<PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr cloud_previous2 = new PointCloud<PointXYZRGBA>;

Comment: Alternatively declare the variables here and new them in the constructor.

Comment: @NerimanArif, So pass `-std=c++11` to the compiler.